# Выход за пределы массива C#

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
public Polibius(List<char> inputKey, List<char> inputAlphabet)
    {
        Alphabet = new List<List<char>>(5);

        List<char> distinctInputKey = inputKey.Distinct().ToList();
        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < sideOfSquare && i < distinctInputKey.Count; j++)
        {
            Alphabet[i].Add(distinctInputKey[j]);
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

На вход функции приходит входное слово и алфавит. Алфавит хранится в матрице обязательно 5 * 5, в алфавите 25 уникальных символов. Пытаюсь записать матрицу с алфавитом таким образом: первые строки - буквы из входного слова (без повторений), остальные символы - то, что осталось в алфавите. В приведённом коде компилятор выдаёт ошибку внутри цикла на операции добавления в лист (в то время, как все индексы равны 0). В чём ошибка?

**P.S.:** есть ли более красивое решение записи слова в массив (с учётом того, что оно может быть длиннее 5 символов).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В отличие от Си++, аргумент конструктора - это Capacity, а не Count. Т. е. Alphabet - это пустой список. И даже если бы он был непустым, в каждом его элементе лежал бы null. Надо в цикле до 5 вызвать `Alphabet.Add(new List<char>)`.

Comment: еще было б здорово добавить объяснение чем _Capacity_ отличается от _Count_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, вроде как это максимальное число элементов, которое может быть в листе, несмотря на количество измерений листа. То есть, если лист двумерный и capacity у него 5, то на двух измерениях в сумме может быть не более 5 элементов, если я всё правильно понял...

Comment: @neo, а что такое - двумерный лист? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, это лист, элементами которого являются листы... длины которых могут быть разными...

Comment: Оф документация говорит следующее: 
Capacity - число элементов, которые List<T> способен хранить без изменения размера внутреннего хранилища, а Count - число элементов, которые фактически хранятся в List<T>.

Capacity всегда имеет значение больше или равно Count.Если Count превышает Capacity при добавлении элементов, емкость(она же Capacity) увеличивается посредством автоматического перераспределения внутреннего массива перед копированием старых элементов и добавлением новых элементов.

Comment: @Grundy, видимо листы это списки. А двумерный лист это список списков :)

Comment: @neo, нет. koks_rs дал верное описание.